# HttpWebRequest and gzip

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Do I need to specify in my request that I wish to accept gzip, or is this default behavior? I am talking to a WCF RESTful Json service.

```
// Create the web request  
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Actually, you should just set `AutomaticDecompression`, the `WebRequest` will set `Accept-Encoding` for you automatically.

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
```

Comment: Actually `request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate")` is not required, it creates double entry in `Accept-Encoding` like `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate,gzip, deflate`.